# RDP failure to Cisco Anyconnect local IP. Remote Connection to public IP working

Tags: windows, cisco, rdp, remote, anyconnect

I currently have a cloud server hosted and I'm using the Cisco Anyconnect client to VPN it into our local network. I can remote desktop to the server using it's public IP address. However this is not secure as it would be in a VPN. When I try to remote desktop to the server using the local IP that our firewall has assigned it fails.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Kyle

Comment: Can you reach other services or ping the server via its local IP?

Answer (score 0):

RDP sessions are encrypted.

By default, Remote Desktop connections are encrypted at the highest level of security available (128-bit). However, some older versions of the Remote Desktop Connection client application do not support this high level of encryption. If a high level of encryption is needed to support legacy clients, the encryption level of the connection can be configured to send and receive data at the highest encryption level supported by the client. There are four levels of encryption available:

source http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458357.aspx

The above article lists some additional ways you can add additional security.

When you are connected to the VPN are you able to ping the internal IP of the server?